# Why can't I dismiss the Touch ID prompt?

Tags: objective-c, touch-id

I have created a login screen and wish to allow users to authenticate using biometrics. I can get the TouchID/FaceID dialog to appear, but I can't dismiss it using the 'cancel' button.  It disappears momentarily and then reappears.    Is there a straightforward way to find out what is causing this. Many Thanks.

UPDATE: after checking for errors I receive the following in the log:

> Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-4 "Canceled by another
>   authentication."

Code:

```
@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) LAContext *context;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (LAContext *)context {
    if (_context == nil) {
        _context = [LAContext new];
    }
    return _context;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;

    BOOL canAuthentication = [self.context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&error];

    if (canAuthentication) {


        [self.context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication localizedReason:@"FaceID" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (success) {
                UIAlertController *alearC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                [alearC addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                }]];
                [self presentViewController:alearC animated:YES completion:nil];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"error%@",error);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason to this is often because the fingerprint scanner is still occupied by a previous operationg . It doesnt seem as if you have used  `cancellationSignal.cancel` or if you have it is probably not getting trigered . Each time the Scanner is done using you have to send the signal by using `cancellationSignal.cancel` to say that the scanner has done it's job .

For example if the task fails then it would look like this ,

```
text_state.setText(context.getString(R.string.fingerFailure));
cancellationSignal.cancel();
```

try adding the `cancellationSignal.cancel()` above or below this

```
[self presentViewController:alearC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and also if needed in the else block as well .

Let me know if this fixes your issue if not i will look into it